# Objective C - Passing multiple text fields (or converting them to a mutable array) through view controllers to display as labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, uiviewcontroller

I'm relatively new to Objective C and currently having the above issue.  I've followed tutorials and tried to find the relevant topics here and I can get it to work for one variable, however I need to pass more than that between view controllers.

I'm trying to avoid using global variables, saving onto a temp file, and singleton (pattern)(?) (I hear it can get messy).  I'm also trying to avoid delegating (If that's the right terminology) as I get the impression that it's becoming overcomplicated.  In addition, if the below works for one, then it shouldn't be far off working for multiple.

I've explored both methods as posted in the code below.  Firstly by trying to pass each text field separately, initially through one controller name, then multiple.

Secondly, by collating all the strings into a mutable array, and trying to pass this array through the controller, then splitting up this array back into strings/text for the label text.  Both attempts only pass on the info for what was the active textfield after pressing the Done button.

I’ve played around between weak and strong properties and that hasn’t made much of a difference.

The storyboard has 2 view controllers (ViewController and secondViewController), each with their own navigation controllers, and a show segue between them.  ViewController has 2 text fields.  secondViewController has 2 labels.

Code as follows:

ViewController.h (for both strings and array method)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldData;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldDataTwo;

@end
```

ViewController.m (first method):
(Added prepareforSegue)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    //UINavigationController *navController1 = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    secondViewController *svc = (secondViewController *)navController.topViewController;
    secondViewController *svc1 = (secondViewController *)navController.topViewController;
    //Also tried navController1.topViewController with previous comment

    svc.labelText = _textFieldData.text;
    svc1.labelTwoText = _textFieldDataTwo.text;

}
```

secondViewController.h  (for first method)

```
# import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface secondViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelSceneTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTwoSceneTwo;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *labelText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *labelTwoText;

@end
```

secondViewController.m (First method)

(Only added to viewDidLoad)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _labelSceneTwo.text = _labelText;
    _labelTwoSceneTwo.text = _labelTwoText;

}
```

(I'll hopefully update this post for the second method tomorrow morning).

Thank you for your time.

**Update 1:**

for method 2, I'm currently getting an uncaught exception of type NSException.

In ViewController.m under prepareForSegue

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;

secondViewController *svc = (secondViewController *)navController.topViewController;

NSMutableArray *textFieldMArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_textFieldData, _textFieldDataTwo, nil];

textFieldMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

svc.labelTextMArray = textFieldMArray;
```

secondViewController.h

Added:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *labelTextMArray;
```

secondViewController.m

In view did load:

```
_labelTextMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//The line below is what is causing the termination, otherwise, screen shows 2 labels each saying "Label"
//If property of array is set to weak, then both labels appear blank.

_labelSceneTwo.text = [_labelTextMArray objectAtIndex:0];

_labelTwoSceneTwo.text = [_labelTextMArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: So what's the issue? You just want to get data from VC to VC? What your doing looks OK.. Another think you can do is put all labels in a dictionary, and create a setup method that takes the dictionary, and it sets itself up after you have initialized.

Comment: Hi, that's right Jay, the issue is that only one label shows in the second VC at any one time.  And the label that shows depends on which textfield in the first VC had the cursor editing it before the done button was pressed.

  Thanks for the dictionary suggestion.  Is this like passing an array but instead using dictionary?  I'll look more into it and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Tons of ways to approach this. A quick search of SO will show that its answered many times. How to pass data between view controllers.... You can also find good samples using Google. A quick tip. Think of the fields as data, you can pass an array, struct, dictionary etc. Define it in both places so that you can reference it. Create the data in vc 1 and assign it to vc 2 as you are segueing to the second scene. Search first as posting without searching will result in the question being flagged as a duplicate and closed. That's how SO works in general. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final working code:**
*For method 2:*

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {  
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    secondViewController *controller = (secondViewController *)navController.topViewController;

    NSMutableArray *textFieldMArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_textFieldData.text, _textFieldDataTwo.text, nil];
    controller.labelTextMArray = textFieldMArray;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _labelSceneTwo.text = [_labelTextMArray objectAtIndex:0];
    _labelTwoSceneTwo.text = [_labelTextMArray objectAtIndex:1];
)
```

*For method 1:*
Pretty much the same code, make sure the strings are `strong` as well, e.g. remove the `weak`.

**How we got there**
First I would suggest changing your `prepareForSeque` method quite a bit.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    //include the code for the navigationController
    secondViewController *destinationController = (secondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    destinationController.labelText = self.textFieldData.text;
    destinationController.labelTwoText = self.textFieldDataTwo.text;
}
```

You should give the class a name that starts with an upper case letter like `SecondViewController`, that is just basic coding convention.

Regarding option 2:

```
NSMutableArray *textFieldMArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_textFieldData, _textFieldDataTwo, nil];
svc.labelTextMArray = textFieldMArray;
```

You should remove the line `_labelTextMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in prepareForSegue and in viewDidLoad.

And I am not sure if `navController.topViewController` works the way you expect it to, I dont know if the topViewController is already updated. I would recommend getting the new viewController the way I already wrote down.

Comment: Hello, I'll give this a go in the morning (away from work mac laptop,)   `;` missing may be due to copy error I'll check on that.
Thanks for the coding convention correction.
<br/><br/>
The issue I seem to have is that only 1 label shows at any one time.  And it's only the label that had the textfield active in the first view controller.

Comment: Hi again, I've replaced the prepareforsegue method and get the following warning and errors.  Warning at *destinationController - Incompatible pointer types initialzing 'UINavigationControleer *' with an expression of type 'secondViewController'.

Next two lines each have - Property 'labelText' not found on object of type 'UINavigationController.

Comment: yeah, im sorry, i changed the code... was just a minor mistake, i wrote `UINavigationController` instead of `secondViewController` as the type of `destinationController`

Comment: No worries, I've put in the correction, it's not liking the lines `destinationController.labelText = self.textFieldData.text;
    destinationController.labelTwoText = self.textFieldDataTwo.text;` as it's giving me an uncaught exception error

Comment: in what way? if you did adapt my changes at least the warnings should have went away

Comment: It did, and the simulation runs.  But once I put text in the text fields and press the done button, the simulation terminates with uncaught exception of type NSException.   No warnings however as you say.

Comment: Where does it crash? Your second method of doing it contains some logic breaking mistakes...

Comment: I've updated method 2 as well now.

Both method two and the suggested edits crash at the moment the done button is clicked as I'm about to go to the second view controller.

Comment: Where exactly? you normally get an exception hinting you what is wrong and you should see at which line the code crashes.

Comment: And by now i am pretty confused about your code. Maybe you can post the relevant code here: http://piratepad.net/96JAJ27DPl that way we can simultaneous change and view the code...